# Update a column of one table when a column is updated on another table with parameters using trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables that have a relationship through `CustomerId`:

**Invoices**:

```
Invoice | RouteCode | CustomerId
1001    | 1         | 90
1002    | 2         | 70
1003    | 3         | 80
```

**Customers**:

```
CustomerId | CustomerName | RouteCode 
90         | AAA          | 1
70         | BBB          | 2
80         | CCC          | 3
```

I would like to create a trigger on which once the RouteCode in the Invoices is changed, the routecode in the Customers for the particular Customer will be changed.

Example:

Invoices:

```
Invoice | RouteCode | CustomerId
1001    | 2         | 90           (the RouteCode here has changed)
1002    | 2         | 70
1003    | 3         | 80
```

Customers:

```
CustomerId | CustomerName | RouteCode 
90         | AAA          | 2        (the RouteCode here must change too)
70         | BBB          | 2
80         | CCC          | 3
```

I have this code:

```
create trigger UpdateRouteCode
before update on Invoice
for each row
begin
    if :new.RouteCode != :old.RouteCode
    then
        update Customer c
        set c.RouteCode = :new.RouteCode
        where c.CustomerId = :new.CustomerId
end
```

I don't know if this is right because in the new  query window it says:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdateRouteCode, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'before'.

Comment: Your trigger syntax does not belong to `SQL SERVER`

Comment: I just got it from one of the solutions here. can you show me how to change it?

Comment: What if a `Customer` present more than once in `Invoice` table and Only one customer `Routecode` got changed in this case what we should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create trigger UpdateRouteCode
on  Invoices
for update
as
begin
    update c
    set    RouteCode = i.RouteCode  
    from   inserted i
           inner join Customers c on i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    where  i.RouteCode <> c.RouteCode 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked exactly as it should.